# How to use tagger file and exe file as library in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am working in eclipse luna and am not able to resolve how to use wordnet-2.1.exe and left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger (tagger file)as libraries. I have currently added these two files as Java Build Path->Libraries->Add JARs... .

These were the errors displayed:

1. Archive for required library: '../lib/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger' in project 'x' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
2. Archive for required library: '../lib/WordNet-2.1.exe' in project 'x' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.

It is important to add these two libraries for the code to run. Does anybody have any idea how to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  jna wrapper library that used to load any Native library .you can get it from this  [link](https://java.net/projects/jna/downloads)

Comment: How can I load my two libraries using this library?

Comment: this link can be helpful  [link](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/)

Comment: Sorry, I dont think that helped.. the problem is different. It is related to how to use stanford post-tagger. My problem is that I am not able to attach two of its properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the Stanford tagger and Wordnet from Java?

If so, you should not include the *.tagger file as a "library". This is a model file, which will be read in by the tagger program. The easiest thing to do is to include the *.jar model file included with the tagger distribution as a library. Otherwise, you can point your code to the particular *.tagger model file with the property (or command line flag) `pos.model`. See the tagger documentation for details: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml or use the tagger through CoreNLP: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage.

For WordNet, you almost certainly don't want to be using an *.exe file at all. There are plenty of Java wrappers for WordNet out there; e.g., [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/) or [JWI](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/).